# Codeigniter Sessions: ignore Wget/1.9.1

Tags: codeigniter, session, wget

I'm saving Codeigniter Sessions to a Database as suggested in [User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).
I have also some cronjobs (wget) running, some of them, every minute and my ci_sessions table gets filled with thousands of records in just a few minutes.

I don't need or want to save session records where user_agent are Wget/1.9.1.

Any idea how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for the [User Agent Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/user_agent.html)!

After loading it manually:

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
```

or by configuration in **/application/config/autoload.php**:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('user_agent');
```

You can then check the user agent with the following code:

```
if (stristr($this->agent->agent_string(), 'wget') != FALSE)
{
    /* wget detected, don't save sessions */
}
else
{
    /* sessions can be saved */
}
```

Comment: Well, it makes sense, but i dont understand what code should i put in the else statement. CI handles the session automatic, this is not some session data i control.

Comment: If Wget is detected, call: $this->session->sess_destroy(); else add data you find relevant to your session: $this->session->set_userdata();